# How to add a div into html code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onmouseover

I am trying to create a function that is supposed to take the mouse coordinates and draw a small radius using their values and inserting them into CSS left and top positions. I am stuck at the part where I am supposed to add the div that I have created to the html. Please forgive me if I am not being clear enough.

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
           function getcoord(event) {
           var x=event.clientX  ;
           var y=event.clientY  ;
           follow(x,y);
           function follow(xcor,ycor) {
           folowHTML =
'<div style="'background-color:red;width:30px;height:30px;'
   +'border-radius:30px;position:absolute;left:''+xcor;'top:'+ycor';">' 
   +'</div>';
        
          };}
                 </script>
                 <body onmouseover="getcoord(event);">

                  </body>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there, but there are serious quoting issues, and you're just assigning the string of HTML to a global variable, nothing more. Maybe  you should have a look at the innerHTML function or jQuery ?

Comment: So You want to draw radius on page in place where always cursor is?

Comment: It will not work smoothly even with `transform:translate` http://jsfiddle.net/WEP9u/

Comment: Thanks, your code works well. I didnt know about the addeventlistener, I need to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try add this line:

```
document.body.innerHtml = folowHTML + document.body.innerHtml;
```

Also You should probably change position `absolute` to `fixed` I think.

### Edit: This was bad way

Here You have answer:
[Instert element before </body> tag with vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801921/instert-element-before-body-tag-with-vanilla-javascript/14801968#14801968)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

```
<style>
    #follow {
        background-color: #fff;
        border:1px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 20px;
        margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function initFollow(){

        var follow = document.createElement('div');

        follow.setAttribute('id','follow');
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(follow);

        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            var left = e.pageX + 'px',
                top  = e.pageY + 'px';
            follow.style.left = left;
            follow.style.top = top;
        }, false);

    }
    window.addEventListener('load',initFollow,false);
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, it'll need tweaking for IE