# Insert element before </body> tag with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
  // element should be inserted here
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not very familiar with vanilla Javascript, always have worked with jQuery. I tried this so far, but that got the element in the middle of `<head>` and `<body>`.

```
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bodyTag.parentNode.insertBefore(myElement, bodyTag);
```

Comment: vanilla is not a js library, it is just javascript :)

Comment: Oh yes it is! http://vanilla-js.com/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) method it can be written as short as:

```
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

Comment: How can we make sure this is the last appendChild executed?

Answer (score 3):

The **insertAdjacentHTML** should work here. You can specify where you want to insert the new HTML: **beforebegin**, **afterbegin**, **beforeend** and **afterend**.

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
    <p>
        <!-- afterbegin -->
        foo
        <!-- beforeend -->
    </p>
<!-- afterend -->
```

In your case:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", myElement);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<h2>Hello World!</h2>");
```

Remember that **insertAdjacentHTML** accepts the raw HTML. You can pass the HTML node with `myElement.outerHTML`.

You can read more about **insertAdjacentHTML** here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

If you want to insert a HTML node straight away use: `document.body.appendChild(myElement);`

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.